# Sitecore Add Link as Section for Rendering Variant

Tags: sitecore, rendering, sitecore-sxa

I have a rendering, which contains an image and text, which I would like to have wrapped in an anchor

So far, adding a Section with "a" as the HTML tag works, but I find, other than adding the href as $(Link), there is little I can do about the target, ID, etc

Are there any other viable options for this?

Comment: Did you try using `Is link` field to have hyperlinks that wrap your content?

Comment: My IsLink dropdown isn't being populated for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use IsLink checkbox you need to define the field to be used as the link target first:

[image]